# @RequestParam name includes square brackets []

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, netflix-feign

I am writing a feign client to consume an endpoint of a PHP API.

I need to call an endpoint which is like  :

> www.myapp.com/number.php?number[]=1

My Feign Client looks like this:

```
@FeignClient(name = "testProxy", url = "${service.url}")
public interface NumberProxy {

    @RequestMapping(value = INumber.URL, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEvents(@RequestParam("numbers[]") Integer number);
}
```

The problems is `number[]`.

If I see the feign log to check the GET URL, this is what I see.

```
GET [https://www.myapp.com/number.php?number[]={number[]}][1] HTTP/1.1
```

The `number[]` is not replaced by the actual value and that is what the API call is failing.

Is there a way to deal with this?

**P.S.**
I know that the PHP API should not have a query parameter like this, but it is what it is and I can not change that.

And I have also tried with `List<Integer>` for the `number` variable, but output is same.

Comment: In that you can fetch the value as Object and map to Integer through ObjectMapper

Answer (score 1):

Are we talking about a `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam` if so it shouldn't be the problem of square brackets. For me it works fine:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/somepath", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public void uploadData(
      @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile fileUpload, HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam(name = "param[]") Integer number) {
  LOGGER.trace("paramValue=[{}]", number)
}
```

logs a value passed through a client

What if the problem is in parameter naming? In the first occurence you write *numberS[]* but further it named as *number[]*

Comment: Yes you are correct about the package of `RequestParam` and `numbers` was just a typo, it is `number` (I have updated the question) and may be yours is working because it is a regular controller but mine is a feign proxy method to consume that PHP API.

Answer (score 1):

You should name your parameter just as `numbers` without the brackets and change the type to a `List`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = INumber.URL, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getEvents(@RequestParam("numbers") List<Integer> number);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried this and I does not work, cause the final URL that feign creates is www.myapp.com/number.php?numbers=1 where as the PHP API only works if it is www.myapp.com/number.php?numbers[]=1.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried this and I does not work, cause the final URL that feign creates is `www.myapp.com/number.php?number=1` where as the PHP API only works if it is `www.myapp.com/number.php?number[]=1`. The square brackets are important for the PHP API. Spring does not put the square brackets in the query parameter which is the problem. If it was a Spring service, then it would have worked but I guess PHP API does not work that way.